# Recuperar valores en diccionario Python

Tags: python-3.x

Buen dia a todos, tengo este valor (diccionario):

```
dict = {'A': [23], 'B': [23], 'C': [23, 89], 'D': [23], 'E': [23], 'F': [23], 'G': [23, 89], 'H': [23], 'I': [23], 'J': [23, 89], 'K': [23]}
```

como puedo mostrar solo en pantalla los que son mayores a 1, (ejemplo: C, G, J)

De antemano gracias.

Comment: `[x for x in dicc.keys() if len(dicc[x]) > 1]`

Comment: Gracias por tu respuestas perp al correr el codigo me muestra: `code`  for x in duplicates.keys(): if len(duplicates[x]) > 1: print (duplicates) ``` me muestra (tres veces el elenco del dicc.:    {'A': [23], 'B': [23], 'C': [23, 89], 'D': [23], 'E': [23], 'F': [23], 'G': [23, 89], 'H': [23], 'I': [23], 'J': [23, 89], 'K': [23]}
{'A': [23], 'B': [23], 'C': [23, 89], 'D': [23], 'E': [23], 'F': [23], 'G': [23, 89], 'H': [23], 'I': [23], 'J': [23, 89], 'K': [23]}
{'A': [23], 'B': [23], 'C': [23, 89], 'D': [23], 'E': [23], 'F': [23], 'G': [23, 89], 'H': [23], 'I': [23], 'J': [23, 89], 'K': [23]}

Comment: Probe mi comentario con los datos de la pregunta. El resultado fue `['C', 'G', 'J']`, que es la respuesta correcta. Siempre puedes editar la pregunta, para mostrar un código funcionando. Así tendremos un punto de partida.